# Удалить в массиве часть значений

Tags: php

Имеется массив

```
  array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g'...);
```

Длина массива 365.
Мне нужно из него получить часть (К примеру с 20 по 50 включительно).

Можно просто перебрать этот массив и все ключи, которые не попадают в заданный диапазон, удалить, через `unset(array[index])`

Но кажется, что это не рационально, так много раз вызывать функцию unset()/ Да и таких массивов много.

Если функция `array_splice()`
Но её придётся вызывать два раза. Тоесть сначала задать что бы удалило до 50 индекса. После задать, что бы удалило с 20 индекса до конца.

Есть какие то более простые варинаты, или может не до конца понял функцию array_splice?

Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получить копию нужного участка: [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

```
$range = array_slice($arr, 20, 30);
```

Вырезать нужный участок: [array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)

```
$range = array_splice($arr, 20, 30);
```

Оставить нужный участок:

Comment: Всё гениальное просто) упустил эту функцию. Спасибо)